# Flutter: send message to isolate without `await`

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, concurrency

The title is one way of doing what I ultimately want; others may be acceptable.

So I have a class that already exists.  It controls some other stuff, and has a `start` and `stop` method.  We are now making the list of "other stuff" depend on some settings saved in [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), but shared preferences requires an asynchronous `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` call.  I don't want to have to propagate asynchronicity all the way up the call chain.  How do I avoid that?  (Alternative 1: is there a library that you can persist data with, without messing directly with asynchronicity?)

Part of the problem is that the `start` and `stop` methods can be called at any point after the constructor (and indeed, when I just did `SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(INITIALIZE LATE FINAL FIELDS)`, without `await`, `start` got called before the initialization happened and the code threw an exception.
(Alternative 2: is it acceptable to save the result of a `then`, and later call `then` on it?  Like, do `this._future = SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {return LIST_OF_STUFF;})`, and in `start` do `this._future.then((listOfStuff) {START LIST OF STUFF; return listOfStuff;})`, and similarly in `stop`?  Seems...suspicious, but possibly functional.)  I'd be ok with making the `start` and `stop` methods asynchronous, I guess, as long as I don't have to actually handle that in the code that calls them, but that doesn't really solve the problem that I need the `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` to have completed so I can have the list of stuff, first.

My default mechanism for handling concurrency is Communicating Sequential Processes, so I took a leaf from that book and thought, "What if I started an isolate that accepts start/stop messages?  It can `await` the `SharedPreferences`, then loop over incoming messages and start/stop the Stuff as requested.  I wrote an isolate to do that...and apparently you can't pass a `ReceivePort` in to an isolate (at least not by declaring it in the outer scope and using the reference in the isolate - it gives me an error `Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object is aReceivePort)`).  You only get to directly hand the isolate a `SendPort`, so IT can send THE CALLER messages.  The idiom I see in most places is to have the isolate send back a new `SendPort`, whose `ReceivePort` the isolate keeps.  However, this returns me to my original problem - creating the isolate (and receiving its `SendPort`) is asynchronous, so it may not be done by the time `start` or `stop` get called.  Since you pretty clearly CAN send a `ReceivePort` between...wait, I forgot it's technically not sending a `ReceivePort`, just another `SendPort`.  Can you really only send `SendPort`s, specifically?  That's...really obnoxious, if so.  It seems pointlessly pedantic and obstructive.  ...Ok, yeah, `ReceivePort` is explicitly restricted from being `sent`.  Argh.  I even thought I had a workaround to the "can't pass via scope" problem: make a new `ReceivePort` in the calling code, use its `SendPort` to send `start` and `stop` messages, and jerryrig some kind of handover of the `ReceivePort` to the isolate once that comes online.  But if `ReceivePort` is entirely forbidden from being sent to the isolate, I guess that's out.  So...how do I do what I want to do???  How do I pull a setting from disk, potentially queuing up `start` and `stop` messages while I wait for the persistence library to become available, without exposing to the calling code that we're making asynchronous calls under the hood??  Am I gonna have to make some kind of awful kludge of dangerous asynchronously-modified flags?  I'll be rather disappointed in Flutter if that's what it comes down to.

Comment: cannot you pass shared preferences directly to your class ctor?

Comment: @pskink Then I'd have to construct the `SharedPreferences` object in the calling code, introducing asynchronicity *there*.  The calling code shouldn't need to worry about it, IMO, and even if it did, I think I'm still going to end up with the same kind of problem.

Comment: so create a wrapper singleton class that holds initialized shared preferences (initialize it for example in the first line of `main` async function)

Comment: @pskink That feels kinda hacky (I'm surprised you can make main async...I think), and there's a large category of similar-but-slightly-and-crucially-different problems I still don't know how to solve - but it DOES work, and solves my ultimate problem.  If you feel like turning your comment into an answer, I'd probably accept it.